# Sencha Touch Filter List for values greater than a given one

Tags: list, filter, sencha-touch

I have a list of meeting rooms with the following capacity of people they support. The data is something like:

```
{
            "name" : "Room 1",
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "capacity" : 4
},
{
            "name" : "Room 2",
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "capacity" : 10
},
{
            "name" : "Room 3",
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "capacity" : 6
},
{
            "name" : "Room 6",
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "capacity" : 3
},
{
            "name" : "Room 4",
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "capacity" : 2
}    
// etc etc
```

Now I want to add a filter so that when I choose the number of ppl that need to meet the app shows me all rooms having a capacity GREATER THAN this number.

For example: If I say I'm looking for a room for 4 ppl it should show me room 1,2,3. If I search for a room for 2 ppl it shows all the rooms. Etc.

As of now if I use a filter this is what I do now:

```
store.filter("capacity",2)
```

and it only shows me rooms with the capacity of 2. Not rooms with a greater capacity.

What should I do???

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a filter function like this:

```
var roomFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(item) {
        return item.capacity > 2;
    }
});
```

then:

```
var largeRooms = store.filter(roomFilter);
```

P/S: If `Ext.util.Filter` doesn't work with your `Store`, you should create a clone of its data which is of type `Ext.util.MixedCollection`.